# how do you assign a char with a blank spot in a 2d array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

here is my void function but I am a bit confused. I want period'.' to output as a blank spot every time a user hits it. This if statement doesn't seem to work. I have a void print function as well. does the if statement need to be added in the print function?

```
int r, c; 
char p;

for (r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
    cout<< endl;
    for (c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        cin>> board[r][c];
    if(p == '.') 
        cout << p ='' ;

}
```

Comment: When are you setting `p`?

Comment: @VinceDelricco And even worse it's not nitialized.

Answer (score 0):

The program will not behave as you expect the way it's written now. You are never setting `p` equal to anything. I can't tell exactly what you need to set `p` to from the code you've provided, but if you give `p` a value before the `if` statement, it will probably work fine for you.